# Custom Validation on a field that checks if field already exists and is active

Tags: node.js, validation, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a mongodb Collection "Users" having "Name", "Email", "Active" fields.
I want to add a validation that for every document email should be unique. However if a document is invalid i.e Active is false then the email can be accepted.

Here is the model

```
email: { type: String, validate: {
  validator: function(v) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {
      console.log("validating email")
      const UserModel = mongoose.model('User');
      UserModel.find({email : v, active: true}, function (err, docs) 
         {
          if (!docs.length){
              resolve();
          }else{
              console.log('user exists: ',v);
              reject(new Error("User exists!"));
          }
      });
    })
  },
  message: '{VALUE} already exists!'
   }
 },
name: {
  type: String,
  required: true
 },
 active: {
   type: Boolean,
    default: true
 }
```

Problem is whenever i do any updation on this model then this validation is called. 
So if i update the name then also this validation is called and it gives the error that email already exists.

How do I add a validation on email field so if someone adds a new entry to database or updates email it checks in database if existing user has same email id and is active?

Comment: You can use presave and preupdate hooks.

Comment: you can also use npm package mongoose-unique-validator

Comment: Use `$set` to update document instead of mongoose update for example: `UserModel.update({_id: 1},{$set: {email: "abc@xyz.com"}})` this will skip mongoose-schema-validation

Answer (score 0):

I would first call Mongoose findOne function if the User is already registered the Mongo DB, for example;

```
let foundUser = await User.findOne({email});
if (!foundUser) {
 // update user, create user etc.
 ...
}
```

I think it is better to not use logic inside the Mongoose document object. Maybe there is a way to achieve it but I prefer to do these validations in the code, not in the document, it is just my preference.

Also you can try making email unique as follows:

```
email: {
  type: String,
  unique: true
}
```

Comment: problem with making email unique is that when a user is archived i.e active becomes false..email unique will still clash when new entry is added to database. The reason i want to do this at mongoose model level is so when any crud is done on this document then the basic integrity of the collection is not destroyed i.e two documents having same email ids and both active..otherwise i know how to do this in controller

Comment: Oooh I understand, it can cause a huge problem

Comment: You can use pre hook as Shivam answered in your question, you can find a example here https://medium.com/@justinmanalad/pre-save-hooks-in-mongoose-js-cf1c0959dba2

Answer (score 0):

I'd use [unique compound index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/#unique-compound-index), instead of having one more additional query to your db. Your code would look like this:

```
const schema = = new Schema(...);

schema.index({email: 1, active: 1}, {unique: true});
```

Mongo itself will reject your documents and you can catch it in your code like this:

```
const {MongoError} = require('mongodb'); // native driver

try {
  await model.updateOne(...).exec(); // or .save()
} catch (err) {
  //11000 is error code for unique constraints
  if (err instanceof MongoError && err.code === 11000)
    console.error('Duplicate email/active pair');
}
```

Comment: this means we can only have 1 archived entry..i.e if there is a document with email: abc@gmail.com and active: false..then there cant be any other archived entry with same email having active: false ..correct me if i am wrong

Comment: so you should be able to have two inactive emails, right?

Comment: yes in practical applications it is possible that i archived an account..then created an account with same email..and then later on possible might want to archive this account again..

Comment: well if you want to have stale users in your main collection, than you can't really leverage indexing, which will show up in your performance, since every single update/create would require a look up in DB with `findOne`. If you are ok with that, go on with *Shivam Pandey* in comments for the original post. Pre save and pre update hooks are your option.

Comment: Just one thing..to ensure indexing is still used with unique emails..where would you put archived documents?would you delete them permanently?or is there a better way to handle archived documents?i have archived documents in multiple collections

Comment: first of all, I'd test the load on my db according to my production usual load. If latency is fine with stale docs in main collections - I'd go with that. But the problem is that these stale documents can be indexed by some other indices and it means that you're going to spend some resources of your db on resources, that you'll never use (or just very rarely). In case my performance degrades, I'd move them in another collection/database somehow and this kind-of ETL really depends on the data you have.